# Get user's Exchange server and email address in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, windows, exchange-server, directoryservices

H​i. I would like to know the address of my user's Exchange server (assuming she's in a typical Windows office network). This is in a C# application.

---

I already have the user's email address, I found it at `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current.EmailAddress`, after referencing *System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement*

Comment: Exchange server 2007 and 2010 come with [**Autodiscover**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc511507.aspx) -- not sure if it applies to your scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this for my Exchange client application.

1. Install [Exchange Web Services Managed API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633692%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)
2. Change your C# project's Properties/Application changed the target framework to '.NET Framework 4' not '.NET 4 Client Profile'
3. Reference `C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services\1.1\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll`

Now code:

```
var exchange = new ExchangeService();
exchange.AutodiscoverUrl(from);
var server = exchange.Url.Host;
Console.WriteLine(server);
```

Here's the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633692%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx). but note it's for the unreleased version 1.2 of the API. I can't locate the documentation for version 1.1

Comment: Thanks kjosh, this looks promising. I will test it on Monday

Comment: I installed your link but couldn't find the `.dll` to reference. Found it at last in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services\1.1`

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the AD attribute called homeMDB:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms980583(v=exchg.65).aspx

I don't think there is a nice .NET wrapper for this attribute, so you'll need to use a lower-level LDAP API to get it.

Note that with later versions of Exchange (i.e. 2010) you can connect to any CAS role and Exchange will figure out the routing.

Comment: Pardon me, I don't understand how to use what you've posted.

Comment: The call to System.DirectoryServices is actually just querying Active Directory using LDAP to get the userprincipal object.  It's acting as a nice .NET wrapper to read a specific LDAP attribute.  Exchange stores which Exchange server on the same same user principal object, except it's in an attribute called homeMDB.  It doesn't look like System.DirectoryServices has a nice .NET wrapper for it, so you will need to read the attribute using something like DirectoryEntry.  See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313114

Comment: As for my note, you may not even need to know which Exchange server if you are using a later version of it.  In that case you can simply point to the same server as OWA and "it will just work."

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into using autodiscover?
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124251.aspx